# pandas .boxplot properties not working

Tags: python, pandas, parameters, styles, boxplot

I am trying to customise a boxplot created from a dataframe, using `whiskerprops`, `capprops`, `medianprops` but the parameters I set are not working.

e.g.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df=pd.DataFrame(index = [x for x in range(0,10)])
for col in range(1,5):
    df[col]= df.index *  col/10

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
bp = df.plot.box(
            ax=ax,
            whis=[5, 95],
            showcaps=True,
            showfliers=False,
            whiskerprops = {'color':'k','linewidth':0.5,'linestyle':'solid'},
            capprops={'color': 'k', 'linewidth': 0.5, 'linestyle': 'solid'},
            medianprops = {'color':'k','linewidth': 0.5, 'linestyle': 'solid'}
            )
plotFile = 'C:\\Desktop\\example.png'
fig.savefig(plotFile, dpi=1000)
```

I am expecting a boxplot with whiskers, caps and medians all black, but I get this:
The tails are blue and the medians are green. Why are the parameters being ignored?

[image: example boxplot]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of calling out each property and trying to change the color, just use the `color` parameter and change the colors of each property there:

```
test = df.plot.box(color = {'whiskers' : 'black',
                            'caps' : 'black',
                            'medians' : 'black',
                            'boxes' : 'black'})
plt.show()
```

[image: graph]

## Edit

Here is how you can edit `linewidth`

```
test = df.plot.box(color = {'whiskers' : 'black',
                            'caps' : 'black',
                            'medians' : 'black',
                            'boxes' : 'black'},
                   whiskerprops = {'linewidth' : 4},
                   flierprops = {'linewidth' : 4},
                   medianprops = {'linewidth' : 4},
                   boxprops = {'linewidth' : 4})

plt.show()
```

[image: plot2]

Documentation : https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/visualization.html#box-plots

Comment: Great. Thank you. (I had tried this earlier, but was using `df.boxplot` instead of `df.plot.box`. For some reason, `color` doesn't work for `.boxplot`.)  Is there an equivalent `linewidth` parameter?

Comment: Thanks Ian. It is odd that the different parameters require different approaches. And that `whiskerprops` etc. cannot be used to define colours.

Comment: Thanks for showing this poorly documented feature for coloring boxplots. Note also that if you want everything black, simply passing `color = 'black'` instead of the dict will suffice.